# What does AES-GCM provide?

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, aes-gcm, integrity

I am wondering does AES-GCM which uses Authenticated Encryption provide us with all 3 properties (Authenticity, Confidentiality, and Integrity), or does it not provide integrity?

Comment: Usually if message authenticity is provided it implies integrity. If it wasn't, an attacker would be able to construe a different authenticated message under the same key. So although they are different properties, they are closely related.

Comment: A piece of recommended [reading](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/36960) from our picked [list](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/36960)

Answer (score 3):

AES-GCM ([Galois Counter Mode](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf)) internally uses AES in [CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CTR) that can provide **confidentiality** and at most Ind-CPA security. AES-GCM also uses GHASH to provide **integrity** and **authentication** like any secure MAC.

In the end, AES-GCM constitutes an authenticated encryption (AE) mode with Associated Data ( AEAD).

One should be careful when using AES-GCM since [there are many pitfalls](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84357/18298) and if you want to use it use AES-GCM-SIV which is safe from IV-reuse problems.

Keep in mind that the authentication is here mutual authentication ( both parties has the same right on the authentication, and should not be confused with the digital signature that can provide non-repudiation.

|  | Hash | MACs | Digital signatures |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integrity | Yes | Yes | yes |
| Authentication | **No** | Yes | Yes |
| Non-Repuditiation | **No** | **No** | Yes |