# In a AES-CBC + HMAC architecture, Is it secure to send a second IV in a message to a device incapable of producing satisfactory random numbers?

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, initialization-vector

There are many [threads](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/why-cant-the-iv-be-predictable-when-its-said-it-doesnt-need-to-be-a-secret) here explaining the need of a random and unpredictable IV for the AES-CBC.

I am building a home automation system with security for a school project where a Raspberry Pi creates a separated WPA2 network to communicate with many ESP8266 Wi-fi modules via HTTP requests. Each new message from the central node is encrypted with a key and a newly generated(using "/dev/urandom") IV.

The message payload structure is:

```
plain-text IV || cipher-text || HMAC-SHA256
```

However, the answer of a GET request needs to be encrypted  too. From what I read, encrypting the answer with the same IV from the received request may not be the ideal.

So is it okay for the central node to send another IV, which the esp8266 is going to use for encrypting the answer?

And what is the best way to send this IV?

1. Inside the encrypted message(cipher), or
2. As plaintext, making the payload:

   ```
   IV2 || IV1 || cipher || HMAC(hash of IV2 || IV1 || cipher)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what is the best way to send this IV?

CBC IVs need to be unpredictable to attackers. If you just send them along your other IV they are no longer unpredictable, hence encrypting them as well would be the way to go and should provide reasonable security.

> `plain-text IV || cipher-text || HMAC-SHA256`

What you are doing here is the infamous Mac-Then-Encrypt with CBC. This is a *really bad* idea. A *really, really, really bad* idea. This is the source of *many* attacks on TLS. Please, learn from the [past mistakes done with TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Attacks_against_TLS.2FSSL) and use a pre-made authenticated encryption mode, such as [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode), or [at least Encrypt-Then-Mac with CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26638/23623).

Comment: BTW, I'm kinda sorry if you feel offended by the formulation of the second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe I was not clear, but I am first encrypting and then MAC'ing the (IV || cipher). I am really a beginner at crypto. Why should I prefer Encrypt-Then-Mac CTR instead of Encrypt-Then-Mac CBC?

Comment: @VictorVal CTR has the advantage of being faster, having relaxed IV requirements (uniqueness vs unpredictability) and requires no padding to a multiple of the block size. The biggest down-side is of course that on IV re-use CBC leaks how long the common prefix is and CTR leaks the XOR of the plaintexts.